# Mechanize - Python

Tags: python-2.7, https, saml, mechanize-python

I am using **mechanize** in python to log into a HTTPS page. The login is successful but the output is just a SAML response. I am unable to get the actual page source which i get when opening with my browser.

```
import mechanize
import getpass
import cookielib
br=mechanize.Browser()
br.set_handle_robots(False)
b=[]
cj = cookielib.CookieJar()
br.set_cookiejar(cj)
pw=getpass.getpass("Enter Your Password Here: ")
br.set_handle_refresh(mechanize._http.HTTPRefreshProcessor(), max_time=1)
br.addheaders = [('User-agent','Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/535.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/17.0.963.56 Safari/535.11'),
                 ('Accept', 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8'),
                 ('Accept-Encoding', 'gzip,deflate,sdch'),                  
                 ('Accept-Language', 'en-US,en;q=0.8'),                     
                 ('Accept-Charset', 'ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3')]
br.open("https:***single sign on login url***")
br.select_form(name='login-form')
br.form['userid']='id'
br.form['password']=pw
response=br.submit()
print response.read()
a=br.open("https:****url****")
for i in range(1000):
    b.append(a.readline())
print  b
```

I get SAML output which is encrypted but i dont know how to reply with that SAML post to get to the actual page.

Comment: And what have you tried so far? Please provide code for what you've done and specifically note where the issue is.

Comment: I have edited the post with the code, please suggest.

Comment: did u try setting the referer?